# The driver NHibernate.Driver.OracleDataClientDriver does not support multiple queries

Tags: nhibernate

I'm trying to use MultiCriteria in NHibernate 3.2 CR1 and I'am getting the following error: NHibernate.Driver.OracleDataClientDriver The driver does not support multiple queries.
My database is Oracle 11.

Is there a solution?

grateful

Answer (score 0):

This is still an open issue

https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2170